# Form Submit not Working in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, form-submit

I find a strange behavior in Chrome.
I have Form to Edit a Record Details.

When user clicks on Edit in a list of Records Grid. my Page  loads a Form with all the details
of the record loaded in the form.
here comes the interesting problem.
If i don't edit any fields in the form and just clicks submit button.
Everything works fine.

But if I Edit any input field and then click submit.

Then chrome is not submitting the form.

It works absolutely fine in IE

I tried changing my Submit Button

```
<input type="submit" value="Continue" name="submit" class="standard button" id="ContinueButton" onclick="isValidDate()">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Continue" name="submit" class="standard button" >
```

But No Use

**Further Observation.**

---

I notice. i have different text area, text box, date filed. I can change any filed and submit the form with no problem.
But if i change the quantity field and Submit then it wont work.

Comment: what happens in Firefox? Did you try to clear the cache of the browser?

Comment: That space character in `class="standard button"` somehow bothers me

Comment: I tried Clearing the cache No Use.

Comment: I'm seeing this too today (and have had similar issues submitting forms with Chrome in the past).

Comment: Could you post the code in your JavaScript method?

Comment: I had this problem, I was using masking in an `disabled input field` which was causing the form not to submit. I removed masking and it started to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try changing the name of the button from submit to something else like btnSubmit and try?
That should work.

Comment: tried no use- i have updated my observation on the issue. Please look in to the observation i have posted

Comment: Well Actually your suggestion helped me to fix the issue. changing the Name attribute and some JavaScript correction solved the Issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have come across the same issue this morning. I checked in the chrome console no errors reported. Just clearing the browser cache has fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it was because the form tags were inside the table, instead of outside. I'm not sure why does this matters in this instance as I use this same code elsewhere, but when I modified it, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Whats your doctype and html type?
Have you tried closing the tag inside?

Answer (score 0):

i see that this is an old thread, but i just experienced the same exact problem with chrome not liking my submit button.  turns out that chrome was dying because i had an input named size.  i found this by looking at the chrome console.  i'd suggest to look at your chrome console and see if there is a form element that may be causing the issue aside of javascript.

hope this helps!

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955376/input-type-submit-not-working-in-only-chrome (Also: we don’t think the issue was actually caused by giving an `<input>` tag a `name="size"` attribute.)

Answer (score 0):

I am calling a javascript method on the submit button onClick method. And I'm submitting the form from there. My problem was resolved when I changed the type of the input from submit, to button.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this relates to the originally stated issue, but it may be relevant to those who experience an asymmetrical reaction to submit button response between Chrome and IE.

IE, in some cases, is more forgiving than Chrome. I found this discussion while research a similar 'in appearance' issue.

On my form, the problem was the most common one, located about 18" from the monitor. Somehow in my coding I had given the div that contained the form container id='contact' and the form had name='contact'.  The submit button worked in IE as anticipated, with that arrangement using form='contact' within the submit button. However Chrome ignored the button clicks with no clues as to why within the console.

After an embarrassingly long time spent trying various alternatives - creating onclick events in the submit button, etc, I accidentally stumbled upon the real issue.  (form id seems to be authoritative handle for Chrome while IE appears to accept the name value?)

Putting this in here in case someone else stumbles into this scenario.

I have seen this effect one other time - IE is also more forgiving of mismatched braces, whereas Chrome did not play - ignored code that referenced the document.

Answer (score -6):

The problem is in your Javascript code.