# input type submit not working in ONLY chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser

I've seen several questions asked about simple

```
<input type="submit" />
```

buttons not working in chrome, but I still am yet to find a solution.  there is no js/jq attached to that button or to the form's onsubmit. Furthermore, I say it's not working in chrome and not webkit because it is working in safari, as well as ie and ff.

has anyone found a definitive answer on how to deal with this bug?

EDIT: this got voted down for b* reasons so here is a screenshot of the chrome console throwing the error that led me to *my* fix.
[image]

i'll take my rep back tyvm :P

Comment: Can you prepare a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: jsfiddle seems to be down right now, and the submit button in question is part of a custom cms made for a client, so i can't post the official code.  i'm hoping (wishful thinking?) for a more generic cause for why chrome seems to 'disable' a submit button....i'll try to post some snippets relevant to the problem to help the community help me!

Comment: If this "buttons not working in chrome" issue is truly so widespread that you have seen several questions about it, surely you can reproduce the problem in a fiddle without posting all of your code. I haven't had any problems with submit buttons in Chrome, so until I see how you use them, I cannot even guess what the problem actually is.

Comment: i found what i did wrong...i had an input named size that was causing chrome to error out.  i only noticed this in the chrome console, so in my case, i moved that input out since it's not part of the form submit (it's only there for an ajax function on the page)...the real fix would be to rename that input to something other than size.   tysm for the responses tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so i found what was causing my instance of this problem to crash.  Using chrome's console, I noticed that I had incorrectly used an input, type=text, that was named 'size'.  this was causing chrome to throw an error and not continue with the submit.  I moved the input[name="size"] out of the form and it worked fine.  i could have changed the name of that input box, but that would require me changing it in a lot of instances, and the ajax involved with that box didn't care if it was named size

lesson: chrome doesn't like input's named size

that is all

Comment: Are you really sure that is the answer? Chrome does not like inputs that are named "size"? I can hardly believe that. Probably you have some javascript error here instead?

Comment: Sure, this is a big lie: http://jsfiddle.net/CQRs6/

Comment: recheck the screenshot on my question here...this shouldn't have downrated

Comment: @JonBest: I think the console error mentions the `<input>`’s `name` attribute to identify *which* `<input>` is invalid. I don’t think it means that `name="size"` *makes* the `<input>` invalid. Could you post the full HTML just for the `<input>` with `name="size"`?

Comment: <input id="size" type="number" min="0" name="size" />